# Stop The Dialog From Closing When Clicked

Tags: javascript

I am implementing my own dialog with modal in JavaScript. My code defines a custom component for the dialog itself.

```
updateOwner(id) {
    let owner = document.querySelector(`#${id}`) || document.body;
    let modal = this.createModal();

    modal.append(this);
    owner.append(modal);
}
```

The method above effectively allows a custom dialog with a modal that prevents the document body from receiving focus. Now, I want to implement it in such a way that the modal and dialog closes if the user clicks on the area of the modal, but it shouldn't include the dialog area itself.

```
createModal() {
    let modal = document.createElement("div");
    modal.className = "ws-modal";

    modal.addEventListener(
        "click",
        function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            modal.remove();
        },
        {capture: true}
    );

    return modal;
}
```

However, it still does the same thing, the modal and dialog closes even if the user clicked on the dialog area. What am I doing wrong? I tried treating the event handling without the event capturing before and just called `event.stopPropagation()` to stop any bubbling effect.

Answer (score 0):

I will close this question now, as I have found a solution to this problem. By adding event listener to the dialog itself, I managed to call `event.stopPropagation()` to keep the whole modal from closing when the dialog is clicked.

```
updateOwner(id) {
    let owner = document.querySelector(`#${id}`) || document.body;
    let modal = this.createModal();

    modal.append(this);
    owner.append(modal);

    modal.addEventListener("click", modalClicked);
    this.addEventListener("click", dialogClicked);
}


function modalClicked() {
    this.remove();
}


function dialogClicked() {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```